# Is local system data use discouraged in hyperledger chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I wish to implement a contract that is subject to market data which each user has access to in their own LAN, but which they are not licensed to share over the internet. I understand that chaincode is supposed to be deterministic. Does this mean that it is not designed to tolerate referencing out-of-band data (data not available in the log or state) - so it would be hazardous in this protocol to reference this market data from chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric (version 1.0) gives you the chance to create your own distributed networks, via channels. When you create a channel, you decide which are the participants of it, and you isolate them from the rest of the network. Then, you deploy, instantiate and invoke your chaincode, via that channel. So that, you don't share that chaincode and the transactions with all the people/network.

When you execute a transaction, you do it using some parameters. You would define it in your chaincode. You decide whether your chaincode could get parameters or not.

I have found many different questions in your question. Could you specify more wich is your issue?!